# .htaccess not working properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've installed a CodeIgniter project on my webserver (http://sample.org/myproject/).

For CodeIgniters routing rules (e.g. `index.php/controller/methode`) I've written a .htaccess-File in the `myproject` Folder which uses the RewriteEngine. This File is build as follows:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/www/myuser/html/myproject/.htpasswd01
AuthName "secured area"
require valid-user
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Now the Problem I've got: If I call the Page normally (http://sample.org/myproject/index.php/somestuff) it works fine, but at the moment I only call the directory directly (http://sample.org/myproject/), this will only work some certain times. Sometimes it works (after a certain time of this error showing), sometimes it won't work.

Does this have to do with the time until the browser re-reads the .htaccess?

Comment: Try to change `RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] ` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L] `

Comment: is myproject actually a real directory under your $DOCUMENT_ROOT ?

Comment: @anubhava Yes this is an existing folder in which the .htaccess-File lays.

Comment: @Bondye I'll test it as soon as the error gets reproducible :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `myproject` is actually a real directory under your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` and you have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` (means execute if request is not for a directory) in your .htaccess therefore your RewriteRule isn't even firing.

Replace your existing code with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php/$0 [NC,L]
```